# How can you revisit previous quest locations in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

I finished the first quest, but I was trying to get back to that quest and/or quest location so that I can find the ghosts that I missed. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You unlock this ability after the next story mission, I believe. You'll be able to access a map which displays missions, strikes, and raids (although some will be locked or hidden until your character is strong enough), as well as free-roaming in a given area.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the answer! Clear, quick, and to the point!

Comment: Specifically, if he is referencing the first mission (where you first meet your ghost/get your weapon) you can return that area through Cosmodrome patrol by going through the Divide and then through the breach. You also return to that area on one of the House of Wolves expansion missions.  You cannot repeat the very first mission, short of making a new character.